# execution logic of float and double in C#

Tags: c#

I faced one question in interview related to C# OOPS concepts.

```
public class Program
{

    public static float GetValue(float a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Float");
        return a;
    }

    public static double GetValue(double d)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Double");
        return d;
    }
}
```

When I execute `Program.GetValue(1)`, it outputs `Float` to the console. Why does it choose Float, and not Double?

Comment: "not able to understand why it behave like that" it would be useful if you include the behaviour that you don't expect, and the behaviour you expected.

Comment: After execution I found 
For option one  I got answer float expecting double
For option two  I got answer double expecting float

Comment: so, you want to know why `Program.GetValue(1)` wrote "Float" to the console instead of "Double"?

Comment: Yes, I want it. Please explain me in brief

Comment: This happens because you are forcing implicit conversion of the int you are passing. There are a set of rules for determining the order of preference for the conversions, but i'm not sure enough to say why `float` gets preference over `double` by default.
see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#implicit-conversions

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

Lets rewrite the code to a similar scenario:

```
public class Program
{
    public static int GetValue(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Int");
        return i;
    }

    public static long GetValue(long n)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Long");
        return n;
    }
}
```

And now what output do you expect of the following code?

```
byte b = 1;
Program.GetValue(b);
```

I'm pretty sure you expect `Int`. Then, why are you suprised when it prints `Float` in your code? The reason why it prints `Float` is exactly the same reason why my example prints `Int`. Think it through and you'll probably figure out why.